# Android: how to design my app to deal with large data?

Tags: android, database, performance

I'm developing an accounting system and I need your advice in two things:

1. In the Invoice activity the end user chooses the item/items that should appear in the invoice. The items are predefined by the end user and the number of items could be 10,50 and even 1000, Every item has several fields: Description, Price/unit, Key and Serial. my question is: What is the best way to deal with this large data:

   - Every time (new invoice) the app send a http request and reads the entire list using json from server side?
   - Save the items and all fields in local data base and do sync every specific time.
   - Let the user type at least two chars and send a query to the server and retrieve the specific items.

I want the app to be fast and easy for the end user.

2. Is it good idea to enable the app to fully work offline (local database) and whenever there is internet to update/sync the server?

** currently I'm using PHP + MySQL at server side.

EDIT: I know how to display my data in appropriate way (listview, adapter, search..) My question is about designing not about code.

Thank you in advice :-)

Comment: i will wait for answers ...

Comment: put your data in listview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using large data like 100 or more items everytime so don't fetch all the data at a time...

1. Use Load more list to fetch only 10 items at a time.
2. And you can store that 10 items in local db and update after a interval.
3. Also put progress bar in Action bar so user can interact with existing data items while fetching more 10 items.

Doing this you can make your app fetching faster.

Answer (score 0):

since you are making billing App, keep in mind some point,

1 - make your database local, break as many tables you can(not less than 4 tables) for invoices only. like wise, you should do for stock,customer,and as per your requirement.

2 - update local database periodically is better option.

3 - use MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar and my app will check if it has an internet connection once a day or once overtime the app is used if last use was more than a day ago, then check to see if the online database has been updated. If it hasn't been updated my app stops the connection, otherwise it grabs the new database and overrides the local database. But the app always only displays from the local database. The downloading of the updated database is done in the background.

Comment: hey, i have similar problem . I want to store few post (like facebook app) on local database and user can view that database when there is no internet connection. When user connected to internet, then fetch new post. What will be best method to show post on my app( listview) ,either by fetching directly from server or from local database when user is connected to internet??